# iwd with EAP-TLS fails with 'Failed to load <pem>'

Tags: wifi, key-authentication, iwd

I want to connect to an EAP-TLS access point using `iwd`, however this fails because it apparently cannot open my client key:

```
# iwctl
[iwd]# station wlan0 connect foo
Not configured
```

`iwd` says:

```
src/network.c:network_connect() 
src/network.c:network_connect_8021x() 
Failed to load /var/lib/wireless/skybert.pem
```

My kernel is the latest stable one and I've enabled `CONFIG_PKCS8_PRIVATE_KEY_PARSER`:

```
# uname -r
5.2.1
# lsmod | grep pkcs8_key_parser
pkcs8_key_parser       16384  0
```

## iwd

```
# /usr/libexec/iwd --version
0.18
# export IWD_TLS_DEBUG=1
# /usr/libexec/iwd -d
[..]
src/network.c:network_connect() 
src/network.c:network_connect_8021x() 
Failed to load /var/lib/wireless/skybert.pem
```

## /var/lib/iwd/foo.8021x

```
[Security]
EAP-Method=TLS
EAP-TLS-ClientCert=/var/lib/wirelss/skybert.pem
EAP-TLS-ClientKey=/var/lib/wireless/skybert.des3.key 
EAP-TLS-ClientKeyPassphrase=youwish
EAP-Identity=skybert
```

The corresponding, working, `wpa_supplicant` block was:

```
network={
   ssid="foo"
   key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
   proto=WPA2
   eap=TLS
   identity="skybert"
   client_cert="/var/lib/wireless/skybert.pem"
   private_key="/var/lib/wireless/skybert.des3.key"
   private_key_passwd="youwish"
}
```

## OS

```
❯ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

## (trying to) read the source

From what I can tell, it's `ell/ell/pem.c` (called from `iwd/src/eap-tls-common.c`) which cannot load the certificate, but that's as far as I've come. The error message is the same if the path exists or if it doesn't.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### From the file [`pem.c`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/iwd/blob/debian/master/ell/pem.c#L321), line 321

---

From my limited understanding of the C language, I can only deduce from the comment:

> ```
> /**
>  * l_pem_load_private_key
>  * @filename: path string to the PEM file to load
>  * @passphrase: private key encryption passphrase or NULL for unencrypted
>  * @encrypted: receives indication whether the file was encrypted if non-NULL
>  *
>  * Load the PEM encoded RSA Private Key file at @filename.  If it is an
>  * encrypted private key and @passphrase was non-NULL, the file is
>  * decrypted.  If it's unencrypted @passphrase is ignored.  @encrypted
>  * stores information of whether the file was encrypted, both in a
>  * success case and on error when NULL is returned.  This can be used to
>  * check if a passphrase is required without prior information.
>  *
>  * Returns: An l_key object to be freed with an l_key_free* function,
>  * or NULL.
>  **/
> ```

---

### RSA Excerpt

> Load the PEM encoded RSA Private Key file.

---

### So, no 3DES anymore(?)

Judging from the NIST 2017: [Triple DES has been deprecated by NIST in 2017](https://csrc.nist.gov/News/2017/Update-to-Current-Use-and-Deprecation-of-TDEA), it is likely the cause.

Comment: Good idea, the man page does indeed say `Path to a PEM-formatted client PKCS#8 private key corresponding to the public key provided in EAP-TLS-ClientCert.`.

However, that didn't make a difference. I tried encoding my key with PKCS#8 but got the same error.